# How connect to a server via telnet protocol?

Tags: sockets, networking, elixir, telnet

I need to connect to a server via **telnet protocol** from Elixir. How can I do that? Should I use sockets?

Comment: You don't have any choice about that. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP, what's unclear?

Comment: What's unclear is why you think you need to ask the question. Telnet is a TCP protocol, *ergo* you need to use sockets.

Comment: @EJP - why - because.

Comment: I find it clear, I have the exact issue. Some servers/systems share only a telnet access (legacy). Telnet is a protocol, which is not that easy to implement, please have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [gen_tcp](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html), you may also use [elixir-socket](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket) which is a wrapper around gen_tcp